# Ajax $.when returns different object when multiple parameters are used

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

I'm using jquery $.when to call a REST url which returns json.

When I execute $.when with a single parameter I get different object in data1 result than when I execute multiple ones, even though return parameters should all be independent.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    fun1(1025);
    fun2(1025);

    function fun1(id) {
        $.when(_restFun1(id), _restFun1(id)).done(function(data1, data2) {
            console.log(data1);
        });
    }

    function fun2(id) {
        $.when(_restFun1(id)).done(function(data1) {
            console.log(data1);
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

the objects printed to console.log are different even though the two functions should print the same object!.

**NOTE**:

the _restFun1 function is something like this:

```
function _restFun1(id)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.123.12.3/test.php?id="+id,
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data1) {
        }
    });
}
```

which returns a json object, in one case I get the json object as it is, in the case of multiple calls I get an object with multiple other fields like responseText, responseJSON, a "success" string and then in an array the real JSON thing I needed.

Comment: What output are you expecting, and what output are you getting? Seeing the `_restFun()` function, and the server side code being called may help too.

Comment: Copy/pasta the log output to the question, please.

Answer (score 2):

Note, not appear entirely clear at [jQuery.when() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when)  as to returned `jQuery.ajax` call returning array of `[responseText, textStatus, jqxhr]` ("success") , or `[jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown]` ("error")

> If a Deferred resolved to a single value, the corresponding argument
>   will hold that value. In the case where a Deferred resolved to
>   multiple values, the corresponding argument will be an array of those
>   values.

closest example demonstration could find at documentation

```
var d1 = new $.Deferred();
var d2 = new $.Deferred();
var d3 = new $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2, d3 ).done(function ( v1, v2, v3 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // v1 is undefined
    console.log( v2 ); // v2 is "abc"
    console.log( v3 ); // v3 is an array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
});

d1.resolve();
d2.resolve( "abc" );
d3.resolve( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ); // returned as `array` at `.done()`
```

---

See also

[Ajax response has different format when used with JQuery when function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456946/ajax-response-has-different-format-when-used-with-jquery-when-function)

[jquery when documentation for response and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181839/jquery-when-documentation-for-response-and-errors)

---

Response would be an `array` `[responseText, textStatus, jqxhr]`, where `responseText` response from server; `textStatus` `success`, `error`; `jqxhr` jQuery jqXHR object

Try

```
function fun1(id) {
  $.when(_restFun1(id), _restFun1(id))
  .done(function(data1, data2)) {
    // `data[0]`, `data1[0]` should be `responseText` , `responseJSON`    
     console.log(data1[0], data2[0]);  
  })
}
```

Comment: The console log returns my desired object, but why is it contained in a new array named 0?? where is it documented? and why this behaviour only when multiple calls are passed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456946/ajax-response-has-different-format-when-used-with-jquery-when-function , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181839/jquery-when-documentation-for-response-and-errors ,

Comment: Ok found the answer thanks to your two links, if you could elaborate a bit on your answer I could accept it.